# Python - find average of two complex coordinates

Tags: python-3.x, sympy, centroid

Given the set of coordinates, How to find the average of the same?

```
ip = [[100.0 - 11.3*I, 82.8], [100.0 + 11.3*I, 82.8]]
```

The final outcome should be in the case of complex numbers,

```
op = ((100.0 - 11.3*I + 100.0 + 11.3*I)/2 , (82.8 + 82.8)/2))
op = (100, 82.8)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, to create complex values use `j` or `J` as the imaginary unit (as opposed to `i` in most math books) and place it right behind a numerical value, without the `*` operator:

```
>>> z = 3 + 4j
>>> z
(3+4j)
```

You can then perform the usual math operations on it:

```
>>> abs(z)
5.0
>>> z**2
(-7+24j)
```

as well as those defined for complex numbers only from the [`cmath` module in the standard library](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/cmath.html).

For your input of two complex-valued 2d vectors, the correct syntax would be:

```
ip = [[100.0 - 11.3j, 82.8], [100.0 + 11.3j, 82.8]]
```

You could index that list directly to get the individual components and add them:

```
>>> (ip[0][0] + ip[1][0])/2
(100+0j)
```

The easier way to calculate the average though is to use the array function `.mean` from the [`numpy` math library](https://www.numpy.org):

```
>>> import numpy
>>> ip = numpy.array(ip)
>>> ip.mean(axis=0)
array([100. +0.j,  82.8+0.j])
```

Answer (score 0):

In SymPy, vector operations can be written compactly using matrices:

```
>>> ip = [[100.0 - 11.3*I, 82.8], [100.0 + 11.3*I, 82.8]]
>>> a,b=map(Matrix, ip)
>>> (a+b)/2
Matrix([
[100.0],
[ 82.8]])
>>> list(_)
[100.0, 82.8]
```